# WooCommerce payment gateways that support 'add_payment_method' or 'tokenization'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making a theme and trying to test the "Add Payment Method" page (template: *myaccount/form-add-payment-method.php*) in the new Dashboard of WooCommerce 2.6.0. However I don't have any payment methods to add, so I can't see the form.

Here's the code that checks for payment methods to display in there:

```
/**
 * Get available gateways.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get_available_payment_gateways() {
    $_available_gateways = array();
    foreach ( $this->payment_gateways as $gateway ) {
        if ( $gateway->is_available() ) {
            if ( ! is_add_payment_method_page() ) {
                $_available_gateways[ $gateway->id ] = $gateway;
            } else if( $gateway->supports( 'add_payment_method' ) ) {
                $_available_gateways[ $gateway->id ] = $gateway;
            } else if ( $gateway->supports( 'tokenization' ) ) {
                $_available_gateways[ $gateway->id ] = $gateway;
            }
        }
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', $_available_gateways );
}
```

So the gateway needs to support 'add_payment_method' or 'tokenization' to be able to be added via the "Add Payment Method" page.

Does anyone know any payment gateways I can install to test it with?

Comment: How about PayPal? Should be pretty easy and free to set up an account and there's a lot of info out there already on integrating it with WooCommerce :)